# Modify the state with other component for the input in React

Tags: reactjs, components, state

I carry out a project which can modify the price of a product (recovered from a fake API) and then at the click of a button carries out the update by calculating the VAT of 20%. I encounter a problem I would like to have a price state and that in this state it's the value of my input namely {listProduct.price} but it doesn't work.

If you have solutions, I am interested, thank you in advance. (sorry I'm new to React I still have a bit of trouble with all these concepts)

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import '../css/ProductsDetails.css'
import {AiOutlineArrowLeft} from "react-icons/ai";
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'


export default class ProductsDetails extends Component {
    state = {
        id: this.props.match.params.id,
        price: 
    }
    updatePrice = (e) => {
        console.log(e);
        this.setState({
            price: e.target.value
        })
    }

    render() {
        const {location: {state: {listProduct}}} = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="products__details">
                <Link to="/"><AiOutlineArrowLeft className="nav__arrow" /></Link>
                <h1 className="details__title">{listProduct.title}</h1>
                <div className="details__align--desk">
                    <div className="details__img">
                    <img className="product__img" src={listProduct.image} alt="Affichage du produit"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="products__align--desk">
                        <h2 className="product__title">Description</h2>
                        <p className="product__description">{listProduct.description}</p>
                        <h2 className="product__title">Price</h2>
                        <form className="form__price">
                            <input className="input__price" type="text" value={listProduct.price} onChange={this.updatePrice} />
                            <p>Price (including VAT): {Math.round((listProduct.price + listProduct.price * 0.2)*100) /100} €</p>
                            <br/>
                            <input className="btn__update" type="submit" value="Update product" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div className="category__align--desk">
                        <h2 className="product__title">Category</h2>
                        <p className="product__category">{listProduct.category}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    } 
}
```

```js
export default class Products extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {productsData: []};
    }
      componentDidMount = () => {
        axios.get('https://fakestoreapi.com/products?limit=7')
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res.data)
          this.setState ({
            productsData: res.data
          })
        })
      }
    render() {
        const listsProducts = this.state.productsData.map(listProduct => {
            return <tbody className="products__body">
                    <tr>
                        <td> <Link to={{pathname: "/products-details/" + listProduct.id,state: {listProduct}}}>{listProduct.title}</Link></td>
                        <td className="products__category">{listProduct.category}</td>
                        <td>{listProduct.price}</td>
                        <td>{Math.round((listProduct.price + listProduct.price * 0.2)*100) /100}</td>
                    </tr> 
              </tbody>
          })
        return (
            <main className="products">
                <h1 className="products__title">Products management</h1>
                <table cellSpacing="0">
                <thead className="products__head">
                    <tr>
                    <th className="table--title">Product name</th>
                    <th className="table--title">Category</th>
                    <th className="table--title">Price</th>
                    <th className="table--title">Price (including VAT)</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                  {listsProducts}
                </table>
            </main>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside a react component:

1 - You declare the initial state of your component, which is, in this case, the price that the product has before the user writes something. For now, we'll set it to 0:

```js
state = {
  id: this.props.match.params.id, 
  price: this.props.listProduct.price ? this.props.listProduct.price : 0
}
```

2 - Then, in the `render` method, we access the `price` value from `this.state`

3 - Finally, we modify our `input` element so that it gets the value of the price.

```js
<input className="input__price" type="text" value={price} onChange={this.updatePrice} />
```

The rest of the component was working well.

This is the result:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import '../css/ProductsDetails.css'
import {AiOutlineArrowLeft} from "react-icons/ai";
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'


export default class ProductsDetails extends Component {
    state = {
        id: this.props.match.params.id,
        price: '0'
    }
    updatePrice = (e) => {
        console.log(e);
        this.setState({
            price: e.target.value
        })
    }

    render() {
        const {price} = this.state
        return (
            <div className="products__details">
                <Link to="/"><AiOutlineArrowLeft className="nav__arrow" /></Link>
                <h1 className="details__title">{listProduct.title}</h1>
                <div className="details__align--desk">
                    <div className="details__img">
                    <img className="product__img" src={listProduct.image} alt="Affichage du produit"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="products__align--desk">
                        <h2 className="product__title">Description</h2>
                        <p className="product__description">{listProduct.description}</p>
                        <h2 className="product__title">Price</h2>
                        <form className="form__price">
                            <input className="input__price" type="text" value={price} onChange={this.updatePrice} />
                            <p>Price (including VAT): {Math.round((listProduct.price + listProduct.price * 0.2)*100) /100} €</p>
                            <br/>
                            <input className="btn__update" type="submit" value="Update product" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div className="category__align--desk">
                        <h2 className="product__title">Category</h2>
                        <p className="product__category">{listProduct.category}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    } 
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, except that I don't want to display 0 in my input as the starting price but the price that I got from my API to then change it

Comment: `state = {id: this.props.match.params.id, price: this.props.listProduct.price}`

Comment: Thanks @Bafsky, I had tried to do that too but it gives me an error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined"

Comment: state = {id: this.props.match.params.id, price: this.props.listProduct ? this.props.listProduct.price : 0}

Comment: @Bafsky Thank you very much, I can modify the price however you don't know how I could display the price of my API instead of 0 so that I can modify it later?

Answer (score 0):

Start off with the price at `0` (not in quotes) in state, and then...

```
const price = this.state.price || (this.props.listProduct ? this.props.listProduct.price : 0)

<input className="input__price" type="text" value={price} onChange{this.updatePrice} />
```

So if the state value has been updated, that will be used, if not it will check if the price is available in props and use that, and if not it will display zero.

Comment: Thanks, but when I put that in the input:

`<input className = "input__price" type = "text" value = {listProduct.price} onChange = {this.updatePrice} />`
That put me well the starting price namely 105.95 euros but when I put:

`const price = this.state.price || (this.props.listProduct? this.props.listProduct.price: 0)

<input className = "input__price" type = "text" value = {price} onChange {this.updatePrice} />`

it only puts me 0 and not the 105.95 that I want at the start

Comment: Are you sure you have `0` without quotes in state? You could also just use `null`.

Comment: Yes in price's state `0` is without quotes

Comment: And change that to wherever you're getting `listProduct` from... so `const price = this.state.price || (listProduct? listProduct.price: 0)`

Comment: where do I change it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Use the `price` constant is my previous comment and if your `listProduct` constant is working as you say, that should work.

Comment: Yes I did it but it still shows me a 0, it means that the `this.state.price` is `undefined` from base whereas when I put `{listProduct.price}` in value it put me well 105.95

Comment: If `this.state.price` is falsey (0, null, undefined), it will check `listProduct`, it that is truthy, it will used `listProduct.price`, otherwise it will use 0... `const price = this.state.price || (listProduct? listProduct.price: 0)`.

Comment: I applied the changes that you proposed. Feel free to make any more edits to my post if you want.

Comment: That's not what I'm suggesting. The state value should start at `0`. Then in your render method add `const price = this.state.price || (listProduct? listProduct.price: 0)`. That's assuming `listProduct` is working... it's not defined in the code you shared.